# Show sharepoint data on webpage

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

I am missing something really basic!

I have set up a Office 356 SharePoint account and uploaded/linked a simple Access table to SharePoint site collection.

I created the website in Dreamweaver - html and CSS

What do I use/do to show the SharePoint data on my website?

Comment: Created a website mean is it a ASP.NET website which is out of SharePoint or a SharePoint web page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use The Open Data Protocol or OData to retrieve data from your SharePoint. OData is a Web Protocol created on top of Web technologies incluiding XML,Atom,JSON. So you can retrieve the information from your SharePoint using OData in form of Atom entries. You can take a look at the following ling from msdn blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2009/10/21/using-data-services-over-sharepoint-2010-part-1-getting-started.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916571/show-contents-from-sharepoint-list-within-a-grid-on-aspx-page-asp-net-site

Comment: Looked at this but although I have now access to Visual Studio 2008  and Dreamwear MX I cannot understand how I reference my "Data Service Endpoint". The table is in a sharepoint list on the Microsoft 365 site.

Comment: If I type the address to the sharepoint site into Internet Explorer all I get is a default 365 Webpage. Can't see how I even "look" at the sharepoint data directly - can only look through a local Access DB at the moment that points to it.

Comment: Have managed to view the data via the SharePoint site. But still need to know how to add it to a web page on my site  not hosted on 365.